# how to fixed monkeyrecorder play_back error?

Tags: java, android

When I use `monkeyrunner plack_back.py test.mr`, my cmd always send this error, how can I fix this problem?

```
C:\Users\Desktop\eclipse\android-sdk-windows\tools>monkeyrunner play_back.py choco.mr
150520 15:55:02.871:S [main] [com.android.chimpchat.adb.AdbChimpDevice] Error sending touch event: 307 164 DOWN_AND_UP
150520 15:55:02.871:S [main] [com.android.chimpchat.adb.AdbChimpDevice]java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: socket write error
150520 15:55:02.871:S [main] [com.android.chimpchat.adb.AdbChimpDevice] at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
150520 15:55:02.871:S [main] [com.android.chimpchat.adb.AdbChimpDevice] at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(Unknown Source)
150520 15:55:02.871:S [main] [com.android.chimpchat.adb.AdbChimpDevice] at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
150520 15:55:02.871:S [main] [com.android.chimpchat.adb.AdbChimpDevice] at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.writeBytes(Unknown Source)
150520 15:55:02.871:S [main] [com.android.chimpchat.adb.AdbChimpDevice] at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlushBuffer(Unknown Source)
150520 15:55:02.871:S [main] [com.android.chimpchat.adb.AdbChimpDevice] at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlush(Unknown Source)
150520 15:55:02.871:S [main] [com.android.chimpchat.adb.AdbChimpDevice] at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flush(Unknown Source)
150520 15:55:02.871:S [main] [com.android.chimpchat.adb.AdbChimpDevice] at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flush(Unknown Source)
150520 15:55:02.871:S [main] [com.android.chimpchat.adb.AdbChimpDevice] at java.io.BufferedWriter.flush(Unknown Source)
150520 15:55:02.871:S [main] [com.android.chimpchat.adb.AdbChimpDevice] at com.android.chimpchat.ChimpManager.sendMonkeyEventAndGetResponse(ChimpManager.java:187)
150520 15:55:02.871:S [main] [com.android.chimpchat.adb.AdbChimpDevice] at com.android.chimpchat.ChimpManager.sendMonkeyEvent(ChimpManager.java:235)
150520 15:55:02.871:S [main] [com.android.chimpchat.adb.AdbChimpDevice] at com.android.chimpchat.ChimpManager.tap(ChimpManager.java:330)
150520 15:55:02.871:S [main] [com.android.chimpchat.adb.AdbChimpDevice] at com.android.chimpchat.adb.AdbChimpDevice.touch(AdbChimpDevice.java:366)
150520 15:55:02.871:S [main] [com.android.chimpchat.adb.AdbChimpDevice] at com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyDevice.touch(MonkeyDevice.java:139)
150520 15:55:02.871:S [main] [com.android.chimpchat.adb.AdbChimpDevice] at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
```

Comment: this might be related to this one, though I 'm not sure. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16466013/device-press-touch-with-monkeyrunner-on-droidbox-dont-work

Comment: formatted error message